# How do I bring a recessed wall outlet flush with newly installed paneling?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I paneled a wall with three quarter inch thick paneling and now the two wall plugs are recessed in. Do any of you know if the have specialty plugs that would plug into the wall outlet to bring it to the surface and be used as an outlet.

Answer (score 4):

There are box extenders which can be screwed onto the existing box.  They can be screwed directly on top of the old box.

Just do a search for "electrical box extenders" and you will find plenty.

Answer (score 2):

I am partial to Arlington BE box extenders for such applications. The 1-gang version is the BE-1.

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00303FYHS/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_1?pf_rd_p=1944687542&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe-1&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=B000GAQE9A&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=0XH4QSEWDXPFGKCN0ZEJ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00303FYHS)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option is simply to remove the existing box and install a new one at the correct depth. Most of the time, electrical boxes are secured with nails in the back, these are easy to cut through with a hack saw blade.

Comment: removing an existing outlet or switch box is not something I would describe as 'simply'.  Having done it scores of times I know how easy it is to nick the insulation or the wires in the wall or punch through the other wall.  Most electrical boxes in my experience are mounted through the side not the back.